# App for planning projects?

Tags: ios, iphone-app

I'm looking for an iPhone app that I can use to:

1. Plan projects
2. Take photos and write down what I'm going to do
3. Add to it

By projects, I mean building bike jumps and planning them out first, like drawing on the app. Then have separately what would be next. Get what I mean? If you don't tell me in the comments and I'll try explain differently.
So the app kind of has to have it from a builders view I guess. I've searched the App Store everywhere, but I haven't been able to find anything so if you know of any comment away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like [Trello](https://trello.com/) in general. You can make great comments, notes, lists. Add photos, files, etc. The really nice thing is if needed, you can make it 'shared' between a defined group of users. It keeps things nice and tidy for my 'honey do list' and 'groceries'.

Example: My wife will add something to the to-do list and I'll no idea what she means. I'll add comments to the item, then she'll reply or upload a photo.

Very handy.

Comment: I just got this and I love it!! 100% what I was looking for! Thank you heaps :)

Comment: You are very welcome. Good luck with the ramp building!